# Retry operator working with observable but not with subject

Tags: rxjs

I try to use rxjs rety operator, its work fine with observable:

```
const obs$: Observable<number> = new Observable((observer) => {
        observer.next(1);
        observer.complete();
      });
      obs$
        .pipe(
          mergeMap(async () => [
            await dataService.getAllSomthing(),
            await dataService.getAllomthingElse(),
            await dataService.getAllSomthingElseElse(),
          ]),
          map(([somthing, somthingElse, somthingElseElse]) => {            
           
            dispatch(
              enableToasterAction({
                text: "good",
                type: ToasterType.Success,
              })
            );
          }),
          retry(2),
          catchError((err) => {
            return of(null);
          })
        )
        .subscribe((val: any) => {});
```

But its not work when I using Subject:

```
const sub=new Subject();
sub
    .pipe(
      switchMap(async ({ somthinng}: any) => {
        return [await dataService.getSomthing(somthinng)];
      }),
      map(([somthinngRes]) => {
        dispatch(
              enableToasterAction({
                text: "good",
                type: ToasterType.Success,
              })
            );
      }),
      retry(2),
      catchError((err) => {        
        return of(null);
      })
    )
    .subscribe((val: any) => {});
sub.next({});
```

Someone can help me to understand what the difference between them, why its work with observable, but not with subject ?

Answer (score 1):

You can retry an cold observable but not hot observable (subject)
if you want to retry a action trigger by hot observable, you can however move the retry() operator to inner observable. For example

```
fromEvent(document,'click').pipe(
switchMap(evt=>from(fetch('someurl')).pipe(retry(2))
)
```

That way the http call triggered by click will retry 2 times when it fails

Answer (score 1):

`Subject` has an internal state and once it receives `complete` or `error` notification it marks itself as [`isStopped`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts#L83) and will [never ever emit anything](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts#L123).

So `retry()` tries to resubscribe but the source `Subject` will just return `Subscription.EMPTY` and won't make a real subscribtion.

Comment: Thanks.but the internal state not receives complete or error

Comment: Then if you have just `Subject` it doesn't emit anything on subscription. So when you resubscribe to it there's nothing to triggger `switchMap`. Maybe use `BehaviorSubject` instead.

Comment: The sub.next({}) does the emit

Comment: That emits once after you subscribe. It doesn't emit after `retry()` resubscribes.